# Почему не запускается Ubuntu и как пофиксить?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap

Салют, я только учу линукс и пытался сделать квоты на устройстве /dev/sda5, получилось так, что в fstab прописал всем устройствам параметры usrquota, grpquota (так как когда прописывал mount, не видел чтоб хоть у одного устройства были эти параметры). После того как я везде в фстабе это прописал, я все равно при выводе mount не увидел нигде этих параметров и решил ребутнуть Убунту. При буте получаю вот такое - https://prnt.sc/vfbrz9 Пожалуйста дайте степ-бай-степ гайды с объяснениями как это фиксится и почему такое произошло (иначе было бы разумнее просто переустановить на виртуальной машине ОС, надо именно понять, что случилось) Спасибо!

Comment: Step-by-step guide переводится как «пошаговые инструкции». Ну и так далее... Картинки, кстати, текстом вставляйте.

Comment: шаг 1: загрузиться с live-cd/dvd/usb. шаг 2: убрать всё что наредактировали. шаг 3: извлечь live-cd/dvd/usb. шаг 4: перезагрузить компьютер.

Comment: @0andriy не совсем понял к чему был сказан перевод к степ-бай-степ гайдам? без вас не догадался бы думаете?))

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо, попробуем